Unable to overlap top Navigation on header in React Native using zIndex
I am unable to overlap TopNavigation(TopNavigation.js) on Header(Inside Sidebar.js) of my react native app, Code:
App.js

import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import StackNavigation from "./src/routes/stackNavigation";
import { createNotifications } from "react-native-notificated";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native";


export default function App() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
        <NavigationContainer>
            <StackNavigation />
        </NavigationContainer>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

StackNavigation.js
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack"
import AuthScreen from "../../screens/auth"
import SplashScreen from "../../screens/splash"
import Main from "../../screens/main"

const Stack = createStackNavigator()
export default StackNavigation = () =>{
    return(
        <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
            headerShown:false
        }}
        >
            <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={AuthScreen}  />
            <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}

Main.js
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import Sidebar from '../../routes/appDrawer'

const Main = (navigation) => {
  return (
    <Sidebar />
  )
}

export default Main

Sidebar.js
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerToggleButton} from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import ClientKudos from "../../screens/sidebarScreens/cliendKudos";
import BottomTab from "../bottomNavigation";
import { Button, Image } from "react-native";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import HamburgerIcon from '../../assets/icons/hamburger.svg'
import BellIcon from '../../assets/icons/bell.svg'
import AwardsScreen from "../../screens/bottomTabScreens/Awards";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function Sidebar(){
    return(
        <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={(props)=>{
            return(
                <CustomSideBar {...props}  />
            )
        }}
        screenOptions={{
            // headerShown:false,
            drawerPosition:'left',
            header:()=>(
                <Header />
            ),

        }}  >
            <Drawer.Screen name="BottomTab" component={BottomTab} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    )
}

function CustomSideBar({navigation}){
    return(
        <Button 
        title="Go somewhere" 
        onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('ClientKudos')}
        />
    )
}

function Header({navigation}){
    //Redux Selector
  const profile = useSelector((state)=>state.profile)
    return(
        <View style={{
            backgroundColor:'#071724',
            height:100,
            position: 'relative', // Allow overlap
            zIndex: 1, // Ensure it stays behind the top navigation
            }}>
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
            <HamburgerIcon width={40} height={40} fill="#000000" /> 
            <Image source={{
                uri:profile.user_profile_src
            }}
            height={40}
            width={40}
            />
            <BellIcon />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Sidebar


BottomTab.js

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Main from "../../screens/main";
import HomeScreen from "../../screens/bottomTabScreens/home";
import AnnouncementsScreen from "../../screens/bottomTabScreens/Announcements";
import AloksCornerScreen from "../../screens/bottomTabScreens/AloksCorner";
import AwardsScreen from "../../screens/bottomTabScreens/Awards";
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import HomeIcon from '../../assets/icons/home.svg';
import WhatsNewIcon from '../../assets/icons/whatsNew.svg';
import RemoteCornerIcon from '../../assets/icons/RemoteCornerIcon.svg';
import AwardsIcon from '../../assets/icons/awards.svg';
import PostIcon from '../../assets/icons/postIcon.svg'
import ClientKudos from '../../screens/sidebarScreens/cliendKudos';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
// const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

function BottomTab(){
    return(
        <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{
            headerShown:false,
            tabBarStyle:{
               paddingHorizontal:25,
               height:75,
               paddingBottom:13,
               shadowColor: '#B2B2B2',
               shadowOffset: { width: -2, height: -3 },
               shadowOpacity: 0.25,
               shadowRadius: 10,
               elevation: 5, // Android shadow
            },
            tabBarLabelStyle:{
                fontSize:12
            },
        }}>
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" options={{
                title:"Home",
                tabBarIcon:({color})=>{
                    return <HomeIcon />
                }
            }} 
            component={HomeScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Announcements"
            options={{
                title:'What\'s New',
                tabBarIcon:({color})=>{
                    return <WhatsNewIcon />
                }

            }}
            component={AnnouncementsScreen} />

            <Tab.Screen
            name="Post"
            options={{
                title:'Post',
                tabBarLabelStyle:{color:'#1C2B41',fontSize:12,position:'absolute',bottom:5},
                tabBarIcon:({color})=>(
                    <View style={{
                        position:'absolute',
                        bottom:10,
                        backgroundColor:'white',
                        borderTopLeftRadius:50 ,
                        borderTopRightRadius:50
                    }}>
                    <View style={{
                        
                    }}>
                        <PostIcon  />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                )
            }}
            component={ClientKudos}
            />

            <Tab.Screen 
            name="AloksCorner"
            options={{
                title:"Remote",
                tabBarIcon:({color})=>{
                    return <RemoteCornerIcon />
                }
            }}
            component={AloksCornerScreen} />

            <Tab.Screen name="Awards"
            options={{
                title:"Awards",
                tabBarIcon:()=>{
                    return <AwardsIcon />
                }
            }}
            component={AwardsScreen} />

        </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}

export default BottomTab

HomeScreen.js
import { View, Text, Image } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import Sidebar from '../../../routes/appDrawer'
import TopNavigation from '../../../routes/topNavigation'
const HomeScreen = (navigation) =>{
    return(
         <TopNavigation />
    )
}

export default HomeScreen

TopNavigation.js

import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import HomeScreen from '../../screens/bottomTabScreens/home';
import BlogScreen from '../../screens/topTabScreens/blogs';
import GalleryScreen from '../../screens/topTabScreens/gallery';
import EmagazineScreen from '../../screens/topTabScreens/eMagazine';
import TopWallNavigation from '../wallNavigation';
import BlogIcon from '../../assets/icons/blog.svg';
import PeopleIcon from '../../assets/icons/people.svg';
import GalleryIcon from '../../assets/icons/gallery.svg';
import EmagazineIcon from '../../assets/icons/eMagazine.svg';
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const TopTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginHorizontal: 8,
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 2, // Ensure it stays in front of the header
    top: -100, // Adjust to overlap the header as desired
    width: width - 16, // to account for marginHorizontal
    height: '100%', // adjust as needed
  },
  iconContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  icon: {
    width: 30, // Adjust the size as needed
    height: 30
  },
});

function TopNavigation() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TopTab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarItemStyle: {
            width: 90,
          },
          // tabBarScrollEnabled: true,
          tabBarLabelStyle: {
            fontSize: 14,
            marginTop:13,
            color:''
          },
        }}
      >
        <TopTab.Screen
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: () => (
              <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                <BlogIcon style={styles.icon} />
              </View>
            ),
          }}
          name="wall"
          component={TopWallNavigation}
        />
        <TopTab.Screen
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: () => (
              <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                <BlogIcon style={styles.icon} />
              </View>
            ),
          }}
          name="blogs"
          component={BlogScreen}
        />
        <TopTab.Screen
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: () => (
              <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                <PeopleIcon style={styles.icon} />
              </View>
            ),
          }}
          name="people"
          component={BlogScreen}
        />
        <TopTab.Screen
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: () => (
              <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                <GalleryIcon style={styles.icon} />
              </View>
            ),
          }}
          name="gallery"
          component={GalleryScreen}
        />
        {/* <TopTab.Screen
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: () => (
              <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                <EmagazineIcon style={styles.icon} />
              </View>
            ),
          }}
          name="eMagazine"
          component={EmagazineScreen}
        /> */}
      </TopTab.Navigator>
    </View>
  );
}

export default TopNavigation;

Required Design
enter image description here
What i coded
enter image description here
I want TopNavigation to render above header in react native app in ios and android both
